# Filtering rows of a dataframe based on values in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter the rows of a dataframe that contains values less than ,say 10.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df = df[df <10]
```

gives,

```
A   B    C    D
0  5.0 NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
2  0.0 NaN  6.0  NaN
3  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
5  6.0 NaN  NaN  NaN
6  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
7  NaN NaN  NaN  7.0
8  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
9  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Expected:

```
0   5  57  87  95
2   0  80   6  82
5   6  33  74  75
7  71  44  60   7
```

Any suggestions on how to obtain expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
np.random.seed(21)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

If want filter by any value of condition, is necessary add [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test at least one `True` of boolean `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df[(df < 10).any(axis=1)]
print (df1)
    A   B   C   D
0  73  79  56   4
5   5  18  70  50
7   5  80  35  91
9   6  84  90  28
```

---

```
print (df < 10)
       A      B      C      D
0  False  False  False   True
1  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False
4  False  False  False  False
5   True  False  False  False
6  False  False  False  False
7   True  False  False  False
8  False  False  False  False
9   True  False  False  False

print ((df < 10).any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7     True
8    False
9     True
dtype: bool
```