# pandas - why cannot I concat objects based on simple booleans?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm imputing certain rows with NaNs. My approach is to generate series of random integers with `np.random.randint`, fill the rows having NaNs with zeros and then again replace those zeros with generated numbers. A simple approach with only three lines of code:

```py
# Generate random numbers for the missing no. of rows
gen_data = pd.Series(np.random.randint(60, 70, size=270))

# Replace NaNs with 0s for easier boolean matching
data["depth"].fillna(0. , inplace=True)

# Replace 0s with the above generated series
data.loc[(data.cut == "Ideal") & (data.depth == 0.), ["depth"]] = gen_data
```

Unfortunately this does not work as I had thought probably because the above command works for a whole column instead of a certain subset of it? I have also tried using apply and concat, but they return errors.

**Edit:**

For a single conditional, this seems to work, but when I try something like this:

```py
data.loc[(data.cut == "Ideal") & (data.depth.isna()), "depth"] = ideal_data
data.loc[(diamond_data.cut == "Premium") & (data.depth.isna()), "depth"] = prem_data
data.loc[(diamond_data.cut == "Very Good") & (data.depth.isna()), "depth"] = vGood_data
data.loc[(diamond_data.cut == "Good") & (data.depth.isna()), "depth"] = good_data
data.loc[(diamond_data.cut == "Fair") & (data.depth.isna()), "depth"] = fair_data
```

I get no errors but a very strange output:

```
data[data.isna()]

    carat   cut     color   clarity     depth   table   x   y   z   price
0   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
4   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
26962   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
26963   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
26964   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
26965   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
26966   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Should certainly work, I believe there is a bug here.

Comment: Some problem with solution?

Comment: Thanks Jezrael. Yes, there seems to be some problem when trying to replace with multiple `cut` conditions. Sometimes Python acts in strange ways. I'll see if I can fix this and get back here.

Comment: Is possible see your solution?

Comment: Ok. Editing....

Comment: No I'm actually replacing the na. Did not run `.fillna()`.

Comment: So you need `data[data.isna().any(axis=1)]` for test if at least one `NAN` per row?

Comment: You cannot filter by boolean DataFrame `data.isna()`, need boolean Series `data.isna().any(axis=1)` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: Strangely when I run the above command per cell in a notebook, then the missing values are filled. But running all at once in one single cell returns that output... Btw, solution actually works :)

Comment: I think problem is similar [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58128354/2901002) for filtering.

Comment: Will try that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `[]` from `depth` for assign to column like `Series`, not like one column `DataFrame`:

```
data.loc[(data.cut == "Ideal") & (data.depth == 0.), "depth"] = gen_data
```

Another idea is count number of values for replace `0` if exist and missing values:

```
# Replace NaNs with 0s for easier boolean matching
data["depth"].fillna(0. , inplace=True)

mask = (data.cut == "Ideal") & (data.depth == 0.)

# Replace 0s with the above generated array
data.loc[mask , "depth"] = np.random.randint(60, 70, size=mask.sum())
```

If no `0` in `depth` only missing values:

```
mask = (data.cut == "Ideal") & (data.depth.isna())

# Replace 0s with the above generated array
data.loc[mask , "depth"] = np.random.randint(60, 70, size=mask.sum())
```